# How to read xml file from windows form application in c#

Tags: c#, xml

How to read xml file from windows form application in c#? 
 I am new in this .net framework prograaming. I have 3.5 .net framework
 please give simple program for it

Comment: @mangesh - can you rewrite your question with a little bit more information about what you are trying to achieve. As it stands now you're not going to get any answers and are likely to be down-voted.

Comment: Not to mention, even my 3 year old knows down cold that when you ask for something, you say "Please", not just "give".

Comment: @DVK: your 3 year old is presumably a native English speaker, which isn't true of everyone on the planet.

Comment: (1) My kid is actually NOT a native English speaker, nor am I. (2) Every language on the planet that I'm aware of has a "please" equivalent.  I'd be very glad if you provided counter-example before adding snide "I'm a sensitive multiculturalist and you're not" remarks. (3) It's one of the very first words people learn when learning English, which the questioner obviously knows to some extent. (4) I wasn't commenting on quality of grammar, but on level of politeness.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to read an XML file into memory is to use the XDocument.Load method.  This method takes a file path and returns an XDocument instance which can be used to query the contents

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\path\to\the\xmlfile.xml");
```

If you're working with an older API, you may need to use the XmlDocument class.  It can be loaded in the following way

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\path\to\the\xmlfile.xml");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .Net 3.5 or later, you can use the [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) class to read and write XML.

If you're still in .Net 2.0, you can use the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(VS.80).aspx) class.